# Compare date times in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can we compare 2 date times and return the difference?

Let say I have 2 values in my session

```
date: Feb 17 2021
time: 0:15 <- `it's AM`
```

and I want to compare those values with current timestamp (today, this minute, this second) and see how many hours/days/etc. has been passed since `Feb 17 2021 0:15`

**How can we do that in kotlin?**

Comment: thousands of solutions on SO for java will work for kotlin.

Comment: @sidgate such a big help thank you so much! :| if I could find working solution for me I wouldn't ask here don't you think?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using [`LocalDateTime.until`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)):

```
fun main() {
    val then = run {
        val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy")
        val timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m")
        val date = LocalDate.parse("Feb 17 2021", dateFormatter)
        val time = LocalTime.parse("0:15", timeFormatter)
        date.atTime(time)
    }
    val now = LocalDateTime.now()

    val hours = then.until(now, ChronoUnit.HOURS)
    val days = then.until(now, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    // val etc = then.until(now, ChronoUnit.ETC)

    println("$hours hours since $then")
    println("$days days since $then")
}
```

Output:

```
63 hours since 2021-02-17T00:15
2 days since 2021-02-17T00:15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I use:

```
fun getDateDifferenceInDays(date1: Date?, date2: Date) : Long {


    // Get the date in milliseconds
    val millis1: Long? = date1?.time
    val millis2: Long = date2.time

 
    // Calculate difference in milliseconds
    val diff = millis2 - millis1!!

    val seconds = diff /1000
    val minutes = diff / (60 * 1000)
    val hours = minutes / 60

       // Calculate difference in days
    val diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

        return diffDays
}
```

Comment: `Duration.between(date1!!.toInstant(), date2.toInstant()).toDays()`